# Include a JS file using jQuery and wait till it loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to include some scripts at runtime and browser has to wait till script loads or dependency resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
    $.when(
        $.getScript( "sample.js" ),
        $.getScript( "simple.js" ),
        $.getScript( "jquery.js" ),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
       })
       ).done(function(){
            //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded
    });
```

Comment: +1, but I would remove the `$.Deferred` bit, it does nothing to add to the answer is just muddies things. E.g., just show the `$.when` and the `$.getScript`s and the `done`.

Comment: Also, "try this" style answers are not usually useful. Always say what you're showing, and why. Links to API docs are also usually best.

Comment: using jQuery's `$.when` + `$.getScript` to get a script called `jquery.js` seems a bit silly, thoguh :-P

Answer (score 1):

You can add `script` element and attach attributes such as `src` with `document.createElement` and place it to your DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve each script via [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which returns a jqXHR object that is also a [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise).

If you need to get the scripts *in order*, you can chain those together like this:

```
$.getScript("script1.js")
    .then(function() { $.getScript("script2.js"); })
    .then(function() { $.getScript("script3.js"); })
    .then(function() {
        // They're all loaded, do your stuff
    });
```

If the order you load them in doesn't matter, but you just need to know when they're all there, you can load them in parallel and then get called when they're all done using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("script1.js"),
    $.getScript("script2.js"),
    $.getScript("script3.js")
).then(function() {
    // They're all loaded, do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises with getScript() and wait until all the scripts are loaded, something like:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript2.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript3.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){

    //do something

});
```

Comment: This looks like an exact copy of Manjunath's answer, right down to the irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

create script

```
  var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script= document.createElement('script');
  script.type= 'text/javascript';
  script.src= 'your source';
  script.onreadystatechange= function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') useScript();
  }
  script.onload= useScript;
  head.appendChild(script);
```

then

```
function useScript(){
//use your script here
}
```

in this way you add a script tag in your head and set a function to call (`useScript`) when this script is loaded.

Note that the `onreadystatechange` handler works on IE only. The `onload` handler works in other browsers